Is Drawing on my skin halal?
As-Salamu alaykum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatoh. I have a question for which I didn’t find a answer. Is it halal to draw on my skin? A friend of mine has some drawings on his hand and asked me if it is haram or not but I don’t know the answer. Please give me a clarification JazakAllahu khayran
